# Missing permissions required by intent Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, permissions

I just added push notifications to my react native app react-native : 0.71.3 version and it was working very well, but suddenly it stopped and throwing error from title. Any solution.

any solution ????????

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.